# Reading field name using GSON from list created from hibernate MySQL select

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, gson

I am looking for a way to have a list of returned from a MySQL query, output in JSON with the field names instead of as an array.  Here is some sample code:

```
List list = lookup_mgr.getResults("select someField, anotherField from someTable");
if (list != null) {
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
}
```

This pulls a list and creates a JSON array like:

```
[
    ["someFieldValue","anotherFieldValue"],
    ["someFieldValue","anotherFieldValue"]
]
```

I'd like it to be like:

```
[
    {
        someField: "someFieldValue",
        anotherField: "anotherFieldValue"]
    },
    {
        someField: "someFieldValue",
        anotherField: "anotherFieldValue"]
    }
]
```

I am looking to keep it as simple and fast as possible. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want is this ('{', '}' for objects):

```
[
  {
    someField: "someFieldValue",
    anotherField: "anotherFieldValue"]
  },
  {
    someField: "someFieldValue",
    anotherField: "anotherFieldValue"]
  }
]
```

This represents an array of objects in JSON notation. As opposed to what you currently get (an array of arrays of strings).

And to get that, you should create a Java bean class, that has exactly those two properties (let's call it *SomeBean*). Iterate over your query results and put the data you need in a *List<SomeBean>*, then pass that list to *new Gson().toJson(list)*.

Comment: Sorry your correct in the curly brackets, I have edited my question. I had something like this, but looping through all rows and building the list this way took too much time for larger lists. I was hoping there was an easier way, but if not, I will have to deal with using the array index since I need it to return fast.

Comment: I doubt that instantiating the beans and building the list would have much of a performance impact. The most likely bottleneck is MySQL / Hibernate. The second most likely is mapping from Java to JSON: you might also want to try Jackson instead of GSon and compare performance for your scenario.

Comment: Your right, the bottle neck was somewhere else, but wasn't with MySQL/Hibernate, it was with a modal class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSONObject`. Simply put your result into it and return that.

Example -

```
public JSONObject getResult(){ 

  JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();

    List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    User user1 = new User();
    User user2 = new User();
    User user3 = new User();
    resultList.add(user1);
    resultList.add(user2);
    resultList.add(user3);

    responseJson.put("result", resultList);

return responseJson;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: and JSONObject is actually org.json.simple.JSONObject.

Comment: Yeah I use JSONObject already, but this poses same issue I mentioned in below answers comment. It's too slow to go through each record and output to JSONObject. Was hoping could get a MySQL result with the column names and able to parse it with GSON.